# get a dictionary of an attribute in all instances

Tags: python, dictionary, instance

```
class Players:
def __init__(self, username, score):
    self.username = username
    self.score = score
```

If I create a class and some instances of it with different scores, how can I get a dictionary with the username as key and the score as value for all instances?
I will change the score after creating the instance, so appending score and username to the dictionary when creating the instance can not work.

thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tricky way is to use `attrgetter` from [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

```
from operator import attrgetter

p1 = Players('p1', 10)
p2 = Players('p2', 11)
p3 = Players('p3', 12)

instances = [p1, p2, p3]

d = dict(map(attrgetter('username', 'score'), instances))
print(d)
# {'p1': 10, 'p2': 11, 'p3': 12}
```

or without any extra imports

```
d = dict((obj.username, obj.score) for obj in instances)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an easiest way, you can do

```
player_instance = Player("name", 0)
...
player_instance.__dict__
```

This dictionary is also linked to the object, so changes to the dictionary will change the instance

```
player_instance.__dict__["score"] = 123456789
# player_instance.score is now 123456789
```

Though, you don't necessarily want to have your object accept changes though this dictionary.
Generally what you would usually do is make a method that generates your desired data structure for you

```
class Players:
    def __init__(self, username, score):
        self.username = username
        self.score = score
    @property
    def as_dict(self):
        return {"username": self.username, "score": self.score}
```